# Method naming for a relation handler

Tags: php, orm, methods, naming

I'm developing an entity and query manager for SQL databases in PHP 5.4. There is a method that joins two queries to a combined result set. It makes it possible to access a relation/association between two tables. Actual it works as shown here

```
$companies = EQM::query('Company')->result();
$projects = EQM::query('Project')->result();
$companies->relate('projects', $projects, ['companyId']);

foreach ($companies as $company) {
    foreach($company->projects as $project) {
        //do something ...
    }
}
```

How would you name the method `relate()`? `hydrate()`, `merge()`, `join()` ...

Any suggestions?

Comment: I dont understand why you wouldnt handle the relationship as part of a single query and then deal with building the object graph during hydration... It seem odd to butild this with separate queries...

Comment: It's the core method for handling eager fetching. In the final version the developer calls only one query and the hydration is done in the background. It's not always possible to call only one statement

Comment: Right i understand that but if you are dealing with objects then your query manager, or a separate entity manager should keep track of all entities (results) in memory. Then when you can fetch something directly from one side of the relation to the other, if the record in question is in mem. it will get it from there, otherwise it will query the db. ie: `$project->getCompany()`.

Comment: In any event out of all your choices i think `relate` is the only one that wouldnt be misconstrued unless this is all internal to your `hydrate` method. Because all the others have a meanings (more or less the same meaning a that) in other ORM and DBAL packages, and to my knowledge none of them work like your proposed design does, so you might confuse quite a few people if you start redefining "terms" :-)

Comment: Thank you for the input. I don't want to confuse. For me it's important to try new ways. That's why I start the development of that lib. If you interested have a look at https://github.com/scandio/troba